# jQuery toggle selector, which is better

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I'm constantly toggling between `#form` and `#edit`. Which selector is faster. Is it better to go with the first or second selector.

```
var $form = $('#form');
var $edit = $('#edit');
$form.toggle();
$edit.toggle();
```

or

```
$('#form, #edit').toggle();
```

Comment: @BoltClock, given that you then responded, does Pinkie deserve an honorary necromancer badge, then?

Comment: This shouldn't bother you as it hardly impact the overall performance but probably the 2nd method is better as the script is smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "fastest" solution would be not to use `.toggle()` at all, but `.css()`.

```
$formEdit = $('#form, #edit');
if ($formEdit.css(':hidden')) {
    $formEdit.css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $formEdit.css('display', 'none');
}
```

Resource: http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/05/now-you-see-me-showhide-performance

Comment: @Neal: Correct, animations would not work using this method. However, the question's code doesn't use any animations.

Comment: Very nice, This is 80% faster then any of the selectors mentioned here. http://jsperf.com/toggle-00

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
$formEdit = $('#form, #edit');
$formEdit.toggle();
//than you can use the combo selector later as well
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It depends.

Are you going to do this operation again at another point, or is this a one-time thing?  If it's a one time thing, there's going to be almost no difference, but almost always using built-in functions is fastest:

```
$('#form').add('#edit').toggle();
```

If you're going to be referencing these same items again, absolutely save them to a variable as in your first example, or, as Neal suggested, save them both to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

The second one: `$('#form, #edit').toggle();` is the efficient way.